# Does the sequence $\frac{1}{\mu([-1/n,1/n])} \chi_{[-1/n,1/n]}(x)$ converges to $\delta(0)$ for any "nice measure" $\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let $\mu$ be a sufficiently "nice" Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Any Radon probability measure or centered Gaussian measure will do.

Now, consider the sequence of functions
\begin{equation}
\phi_n(x):=\frac{1}{\mu([-1/n,1/n])} \chi_{[-1/n,1/n]}(x)
\end{equation}

Then, for any bounded smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_n(x) f(x)d\mu(x) \to f(0)
\end{equation}
as $n \to \infty$.

When $\mu$ is just a Lebesgue measure, I am aware that this is a well-known result. I am curious about extending to different meausures.

Comment: Of course we need $0$ to belong to the support of $\mu$ to avoid $0$ denominator in the definition of $\phi_n$.  What happens if you try to prove it not only for bounded smooth functions, but even for continuous functions $f$, using the definition of "continuous"?  Is it not easy to do?

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the condition about support of the measure..  By continuity, what comes to my mind is the Mean Value Theorem for integrals. But is there an extension MVT for any measure $\mu$?

Comment: No, do not use theorems like Mean Value Theorem.  Use the definition of "continuous".

Comment: It might be useful to understand what $\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_n(x) d\mu(x)$ equals to and then use this to follow GEdgar's advice.